# Laravel cache::remember - cannot serialize closure

Tags: laravel, caching, laravel-5.7

I am getting the following exception when trying to use cache remember:

[image]

But in the Laravel docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/cache) they are using a closure in their example:

[image: closure being used in Lara docs example]

Any help much appreciated ... have googled it and people seem to be having issue with forever() closures not being serializable (but suggested solutions not working for me)

```
/**
     * @param string $guid
     * @return Account
     */
    public function getAccount(string $guid): Account
    {
        $key = md5(sprintf('xero/accounts[guid="%s"]', $guid));
        return $this->cache->remember($key, Carbon::now()->addHour(), function () use ($guid) {
            return $this->xero->loadByGUID(Account::class, $guid);
        });
    }
```

I've now also tried doing this instead (to get around passing a closure to cache::remember fxn):

```
public function getAccount(string $guid): Account
    {
        $key = md5(sprintf('xero/accounts[guid="%s"]', $guid));

        $account = $this->cache->get($key);
        if ($account === null) {
            //dump('account not found, storing in cache...');
            /** @var Account $account */
            $account = $this->xero->loadByGUID(Account::class, $guid);
            $this->cache->put($key, $account, Carbon::now()->addHour());
        }
    }
```

But still getting same error (cannot serialize Closure) at the line '$this->cache->put($key, $account, Carbon::now()->addHour());'

The $account object is of type: use XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Account;
(from https://github.com/calcinai/xero-php)

Comment: Please share the code you are using

Comment: As well what type of element are you trying to cache?

Comment: could this possibly help you : https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23501#issuecomment-428051235

Comment: Thanks @ChristopheHubert I have seen that link before. Are you talking about DanRichard's solution at the very end?

Comment: Yes that's correct - since it's related to queues, it seems relevant to your problem

Comment: Actually I realized this is NOT related to queues, I am testing this method directly (bypassing the queue), sorry my mistake. So I think the issue is with serialization during caching ... it may be that the cache does not like XeroPHP type objects (cannot quite see why though, it's just a PHP object)

Comment: As you have seen as well, caching can be quite tricky with the type of items Laravel can handle...

Comment: Thanks @ChristopheHubert here's solution: https://github.com/calcinai/xero-php/issues/734

Comment: great! Maybe you can add it as an answer to your question and approve it

Answer (score 0):

Models contain a reference to the Xero Application which contain an instance of a Guzzle client, which itself has properties that contains closures.
PHPs serialize function is not able to serialize Closures: https://3v4l.org/1MIpd

A possibility would be calling toStringArray and fromStringArray when you store and retrieve a model.

(full credit to Josh-G: https://github.com/calcinai/xero-php/issues/734)